# Why the extra backward slashes are being appended automatically?

Tags: java, json

I have this below JSON

```
[
    {
        "itemid": "59",
        "toppings": [
            {
                "name": "Quantity      1",
                "value": [
                    "Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And i am parsing it this way using org.json in java

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(orderjson);
JSONObject orderdetailsjson = new JSONObject();

for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++)
{

    JSONObject jsonobjectpar = json.getJSONObject(i);
    orderdetailsjson.put("orderid", jsonobjectpar.getString("orderid"));
    orderdetailsjson.put("itemid", jsonobjectpar.getString("itemid"));
    orderdetailsjson.put("toppings", jsonobjectpar.getString("toppings"));

}

System.out.println(orderdetailsjson);
```

When i ran the above , the output was

```
{
    "itemid": "59",
    "toppings": "[{\"name\":\"Quantity      1\",\"value\":[\"Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML\"]}]"
}
```

The toppings array has got extra backward slashes .

Please let me know how can i eliminate them ??

Why the extra backward slashes are being appended automaticaly ??

How to eliminate them ??

I tried to use

```
String toppings  = jsonobjectpar.getString("toppings");

toppings =  toppings.replace("\\/", "/");

orderdetailsjson.put("toppings", toppings);
```

but not working .

Comment: Because you _put_ it as a `String`. You didn't put it _raw_.

Comment: The backslash is an escape character, since a normal quote (") will be parsed as a character of special meaning (denotes a string). It means that what's coming should be literally the character " rather than what " typically does.

Comment: Could anybody tell me how can i eliminate them ??

Comment: Go ahead and output `jsonobjectpar.getString("toppings")`, so you can see what this function does. You don't want the string, but rather the JSONArray located there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have turned a JSON object into a String and used the String as an attribute value.  The String contains double-quote characters which need to be escaped in the final serialization.  (That is because the quote character has special meaning ... as a String terminator.)

But if you are trying to produce the JSON at the start of the Question, you are building the `JSONObject` incorrectly.  You should not be setting the value of `"puttings"` to a String.  It should be a JSON object.  Change

```
    orderdetailsjson.put("toppings", jsonobjectpar.getString("toppings"));
```

to

```
    orderdetailsjson.put("toppings", jsonobjectpar.getJSONObject("toppings"));
```

or (to be correct in this case),

```
    orderdetailsjson.put("toppings", jsonobjectpar.getJSONArray("toppings"));
```

... since toppings is actually an array.

Comment: Thanks , but how this will work , this will put the whole json into the toppings know ??

Comment: I am getting this exception Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["toppings"] is not a JSONObject.
 at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:515)
 at com.Teste.main(Teste.java:42)

Comment: Thank you so much ,   orderdetailsjson.put("toppings", jsonobjectpar.getJSONArray("toppings")); has worked .

Comment: Can you, please, explain why the extra indentation?

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb -  Simple.  Because I think it looks better that way.